# Angular animations without ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to switch from **CSS animation** to **Angular Animations** and I can't find out how to animate an element from an array without displaying all and show only the selected one with a ***ngIf**.

Animations are defined in the TS file as follow:

```
@Component({
  ...
  animations: [
    trigger("carouselAnimation", [
      // Next
      transition(":increment", [
        query(":enter", [
          style({ opacity: 0, transform: "translateX(100%)" }),
          animate(".3s", style({ opacity: 1, transform: "translateX(0)" }))
        ])
      ]),
      // Previous
      transition(":decrement", [
        query(":enter", [
          style({ opacity: 0, transform: "translateX(-100%)" }),
          animate(".3s", style({ opacity: 1, transform: "translateX(0%)" }))
        ])
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

and in HTML, the selected image is displayed as follow:

```
<div [@carouselAnimation]="counter">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let img of images; let i=index">
        <img [src]="img" style="height:200px; width:200px" *ngIf="i===counter"/>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

All works fine so far, but what I'm trying to do is animate the image without displaying all the others, and use a ***ngIf** to hide them and keep only the selected one:

```
<div [@carouselAnimation]="counter">
    <img [src]="imgSrc" style="height:200px; width:200px">
</div>
```

But if I'm doing this, the animation is not working anymore.

I have also created a demo in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slide-left-and-right-with-animation-cvjudg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Make sure you do not comment out the part of the reproducer that actually causes the problem. Reproducers are there to show a problem or error after all.

Comment: Updated, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you should do is ditch the `ngFor` and instaead use the image like so:

```
<img [@carouselAnimation]="counter" [src]="images[counter]" style="height:200px; width:200px" />
```

The other thing that you should do with this approach is to change the query from `:enter` to `:self` in order to trigger the animation over the `<img/>` element

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/carosel-example-stack-overflow?file=src/app/app.component.html) with working demo (forked from you solution).

The only issue with this approach (that is also an issue with you `*ngFor` solution) is that if the image loads slower than the animation the user will end up with a buggy experience.

Comment: Thank you so much, man. It works as I wanted. So the problem was the `:enter` query, I understood. And regarding the bug you mentioned, is there o solution for this? I also increased the animation time to `0.6s`. And one more thing that I observed is that if the user clicks fast the **next** or **previous** attachments, the animation continues but image src is changed. This behavior is expected, but I'm trying to ask if is there a posibility to 'restart' the animation in this case.

Comment: Not sure about the animation cancelation.About the other issue (with the image loading) you can either prefetch and cache the images in some way so that you are guranteed that the images will load super-fast, or you can create some kind of component wrapper for the carousel, where you will be loading for example 5 images at a time and each time you are going next or back you will remove the first/last element of the pre-rendered images and append the new image to the end (something like infinite-scroll but for a carousel) by doing so you will pre-fetch the nearest images.